# My android app crashes, but i don't see what's wrong

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse

I'm new here and a complete noob. My app crashes on launch, but i can't see what's wrong with the code. i think it's something with the imagebutton. help is much appreciated :D.

```
package com.gamix.gtavcheats;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Xbox360.class);
       MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);       
   }  
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

log:

```
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gamix.gtavcheats/com.gamix.gtavcheats.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at com.gamix.gtavcheats.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-26 09:12:26.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1291):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Remove this line  findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

Comment: We are not GOD here that will understand your issue without logcat and provide you solution.

Comment: post your logcat error message

Comment: post your xml layout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

By this one

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

and try.

Answer (score 1):

Problem because of you define ImageButton in layout but you are Using as Button.

Try like this

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

Remove this line

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

Comment: If `Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);` does not have problem then why `findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);` will create a problem ?

Comment: @MukeshKumar but that line makes no sense at all.

Comment: Ofcourse that make no sense, but that will not a cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show log? In log you can see affected row number. And why after setContentView(yourXML)
`findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);` ? remove it.

Comment: this does not answer the question